Why is my instance of Search Console not populating when I filter by page
There are several owners on my instance of Search Console; mine seems to be the only one that does not populate when I filter to drill down by page.
Filters:
Search Type = Web, Date = Last 6 months, Page = [any URL]
Research completed:

Site and all pages are indexed
Sitemap has been submitted
Robots.txt file is accurate

The strangest part is that others within our GSC instance are able to apply these filters and data populates. Why is it only not populating for only my instance??

@RichardB I appreciate your insight!
I ended up copying the URL and pasting into a browser. Once I copied the URL from the browser (rather than the Word doc) my issue was resolved. There must have been an odd formatting issue copying directly from the Word doc.

If other people are seeing the correct data, it won't be any on-site issue.
I've just checked and restricted accounts should also be able to see that specific data, so it is unlikely to be access control settings.
Two potential causes I can think of -
Is your search definitely the same as what the other people are searching - small things like not adding a trailing forward slash correctly can mean you may not see the results you expect.
Have you tried using a different browser - a plug-in may be causing conflicts.  If you are using an old browser, patch it.
